# TensorFlow: cast a float64 tensor to float32

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to use: `train = optimizer.minimize(loss)` but the standard optimizers do not work with `tf.float64`. Therefore I want to truncate my `loss` from `tf.float64` to only `tf.float32`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q4.py", line 85, in <module>
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 190, in minimize
    colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 229, in compute_gradients
    self._assert_valid_dtypes([loss])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 354, in _assert_valid_dtypes
    dtype, t.name, [v for v in valid_dtypes]))
ValueError: Invalid type tf.float64 for Add_1:0, expected: [tf.float32].
```

Comment: So you want to convert it into float32 from float64?

Comment: yeah. As a temp fix i convered the numpy array from float64 to float32, which is from where my float64 tensor was coming in the first place and that solved my problem, but there must be a way of converting in tf itself

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The short answer is that you can convert a tensor from `tf.float64` to `tf.float32` using the [`tf.cast()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#cast) op:

```
loss = tf.cast(loss, tf.float32)
```

The longer answer is that this will not solve all of your problems with the optimizers. (The lack of support for `tf.float64` is a [known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/761).) The optimizers require that all of the **`tf.Variable`** objects that you are trying to optimize must also have type `tf.float32`.