# TesorFlow Keras GRU layer invalid argument error - 'expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets

I am currently working on an RNN in TensorFlow (and Keras) to generate moving object data. My RNN model is defined as follows:

```
if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
    my_gru = tf.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU
else:
    import functools
    my_gru = functools.partial(
        tf.keras.layers.GRU, recurrent_activation='sigmoid')

def build_model(internal_units, batch_size):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        my_gru(internal_units, return_sequences=True, recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform', stateful=True, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None, 3]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
    ])
    return model

INTERNAL_UNITS = 1024
model = build_model(internal_units=INTERNAL_UNITS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

I get the following summary for the model, which is all well and good:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
cu_dnngru_2 (CuDNNGRU)       (64, None, 1024)          3161088   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (64, None, 3)             3075      
=================================================================
Total params: 3,164,163
Trainable params: 3,164,163
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

When I try to run the model for a single prediction before training, just to see if it generally works and the output has the correct shape, I get an error.

This is how I run the model ...

```
for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in dataset.take(1): 
    example_batch_predictions = model(input_example_batch)
    print(example_batch_predictions.shape, "# (batch_size, sequence_length, n_features)")
```

... and this is the error I get ...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-dd1ea240c0d1> in <module>()
      1 for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in dataset.take(1):
----> 2     example_batch_predictions = model(input_example_batch)
      3     print(example_batch_predictions.shape, "# (batch_size, sequence_length, n_features)")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    755       if not in_deferred_mode:
    756         self._in_call = True
--> 757         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    758         self._in_call = False
    759         if outputs is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    227   def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
    228     if self._is_graph_network:
--> 229       return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    230 
    231     outputs, _ = self._call_and_compute_mask(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in call(self, inputs, training, mask)
    843     outputs, _ = self._run_internal_graph(inputs,
    844                                           training=training,
--> 845                                           mask=masks)
    846     return outputs
    847 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in _run_internal_graph(self, inputs, training, mask)
   1029                     computed_tensor, **kwargs)
   1030               else:
-> 1031                 output_tensors = layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs)
   1032                 if hasattr(layer, 'compute_mask'):
   1033                   output_masks = layer.compute_mask(computed_tensor,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state)
    107       # Reverse time axis.
    108       inputs = K.reverse(inputs, 1)
--> 109     output, states = self._process_batch(inputs, initial_state)
    110 
    111     if self.stateful:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py in _process_batch(self, inputs, initial_state)
    297         params=params,
    298         is_training=True,
--> 299         rnn_mode='gru')
    300 
    301     if self.stateful or self.return_state:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py in cudnn_rnn(input, input_h, input_c, params, rnn_mode, input_mode, direction, dropout, seed, seed2, is_training, name)
    142           input_mode=input_mode, direction=direction, dropout=dropout,
    143           seed=seed, seed2=seed2, is_training=is_training, name=name,
--> 144           ctx=_ctx)
    145     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
    146       if name is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_cudnn_rnn_ops.py in cudnn_rnn_eager_fallback(input, input_h, input_c, params, rnn_mode, input_mode, direction, dropout, seed, seed2, is_training, name, ctx)
    184   "is_training", is_training)
    185   _result = _execute.execute(b"CudnnRNN", 4, inputs=_inputs_flat,
--> 186                              attrs=_attrs, ctx=_ctx, name=name)
    187   _execute.record_gradient(
    188       "CudnnRNN", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result, name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     64     else:
     65       message = e.message
---> 66     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     67   # pylint: enable=protected-access
     68   return tensors

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute CudnnRNN as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but is a float tensor [Op:CudnnRNN]
```

The input I use (`input_example_batch`) looks as follows:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 1.04234461  4.66466794 -4.32528214]
  [ 1.04244826  4.49530966 -4.42294239]
  [ 1.04256889  4.47099585 -4.51911731]
  ...
  [ 1.05549699 -0.64915764  0.67451403]
  [ 1.05559893 -0.7788313   0.66355975]
  [ 1.05570257 -0.88502956  0.65223413]]

 [[-0.83849063 -0.47476892 -0.22299478]
  [-0.8383632  -0.41943403 -0.22782209]
  [-0.83830883 -0.41635987 -0.24527468]
  ...
  [-0.82015615  0.05482504  0.681198  ]
  [-0.8200627  -0.04187127  0.69233796]
  [-0.81995906 -0.13493448  0.66615907]]

 [[-1.27264128  0.12441285 -0.48032767]
  [-1.27256143  0.29544794 -0.714081  ]
  [-1.27247477  0.46871879 -0.97197089]
  ...
  [-1.25435437  3.47832158  0.72724314]
  [-1.25427451  3.90674772  0.63255355]
  [-1.25418956  4.28934093  0.49219015]]

 ...

 [[ 1.01251773  1.16012535 -2.9933152 ]
  [ 1.01263666  1.16906836 -2.99554319]
  [ 1.0127505   0.99943062 -2.95135471]
  ...
  [ 1.02650943 -0.42362607  0.46805359]
  [ 1.02661308 -0.49377282  0.42702143]
  [ 1.02666575 -0.49544963  0.42739276]]

 [[-1.34049978 -0.01029126  0.5430626 ]
  [-1.34038934 -0.04690171  0.52078269]
  [-1.34029419  0.07857991  0.52895199]
  ...
  [-1.3289751   1.94152097  1.03489148]
  [-1.32888165  1.51113855  0.94372954]
  [-1.32878311  1.16208164  0.76511898]]

 [[ 0.57716585 -1.38779448  0.0469634 ]
  [ 0.57728308 -1.44536512 -0.01542033]
  [ 0.57734255 -1.49846425 -0.02581762]
  ...
  [ 0.58594146 -0.63183055 -0.03621491]
  [ 0.58603491 -0.60136842 -0.04419854]
  [ 0.58613855 -0.63015374 -0.07204842]]], shape=(64, 100, 3), dtype=float64)
```

All of this is running in a Google Colab environment.

I have already tried forcing it to use the normal GRU layer, which leads to pretty much the same error. A notable difference, though, with the normal GRU layer is that it claims to expect a float tensor instead of a double tensor (exactly the other way around as the error I copied into this post).

My entire code basically the same as an [example given on the TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/text_generation). I modified the model slightly and changed the input data to have 3 features instead of having as many features as the alphabet is long. The original TensorFlow example works just fine for me.

Please excuse the long post and ask for more information, if you need any. I tried to be thorough, but you never know. I appreciate every help.

EDIT:

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KYP4NRtLSmjclZKik9noo1eZRVBpITlR) you can find a short example Notebook on Google Colab that you can use to reproduce the error yourself.

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I added a link to my post that leads to a Colab Notebook. It's a much smaller example, but it does produce the same error for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution that seems to work for me. When I call `model.input` I get the following output that suggests that the GRU layer requires its input to be a float tensor.

```
<DeferredTensor 'gru_input' shape=(64, ?, 3) dtype=float32>
```

Using the line

```
x = tf.cast(x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

([TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/cast)) I can cast my input data to be a float tensor. Using this float tensor, the model works just fine.

I hope this helps someone with the same problem. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725513/tensorflow-cast-a-float64-tensor-to-float32) `float64` compatibility is a known issue with TensorFlow.